# Phalcon Model order by item popularity (number of appearances)

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-orm

I'm sure I have done something like this before, but can't find it and google not being helpful.

Using Phalcon model if possible, I want to select the items from a table whose ID appears the most - i.e. 10 most popular items ordered by popularity. Is this possible using `Model::find("conditions")`? I do I have to use PHQL for this?

Answer (score 1):

using model::find

```php
Model::find([
    'columns' => 'id,count(id) as counter',
    'group' => 'id',
    'order' => 'counter DESC'
]);
```

PHQL:

```php
$this->modelsManager->executeQuery('SELECT count(id) AS counter,id FROM ModelName GROUP BY id ORDER BY counter DESC');
```

Comment: That's similar to what I ended up doing in the end, but was wondering if there was a simple way to do it using `Model::find()`.

Answer (score 0):

`find()` does have a `group` clause, but I don't think it's possible to do what you want because you also need to do a count.

Talal's answer is close, but won't work if you want a list of model objects.

Something like this should work:

```
$Results = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM ModelName GROUP BY id ORDER BY count(id) DESC LIMIT 10');
$Results->setHydrationMode(\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset::HYDRATE_RECORDS);
```

Setting the hydration mode may not be necessary, as Phalcon may default to that mode based on the fact the query is asking for `*`.