# PhalconPHP - How to return return single typed Raw SQL Statement Result

Tags: php, phalcon

I have a relatively average (however basic) knowledge with PHP but I'm **fairly new to PhalconPHP**. I've learned of PhalconPHP while browsing a specific online course website and that this framework is rather fast and unique than other PHP Frameworks, plus it has a `Micro` package for easy development of `REST API`.

So as it is, I'm trying to learn how to develop an API with the help of PhalconPHP Framework. And as it is, for beginners like me, I'd like to start with using `raw SQL statements` rather than the provided `phql syntax` because I'm not entirely developing an MVC Application (and I'm really having a hard time learning the entire concept of PHQL itself, I need a separate time to learn this).

I have managed to make things work when working with multi-column query results that map to the class much like how it is supposed to be with PhalconPHP, with below sample code:

```
<?php

namespace MyApplication\Db\ShortLinks\Services;

use MyApplication\Db\ShortLinks\DatabaseTables;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple as ResultSet;


    class VisitorService
    {
        function getVisitorLogByLinkId($id)
        {
            $sqlQry = "SELECT * FROM visitors v WHERE v.link_id = $id ORDER BY v.visitor_id DESC;";

            $visitor = new DatabaseTables\Visitor();

            $resultSet = new ResultSet(null, $visitor, $visitor->getReadConnection()->query($sqlQry));

            $data = [];

            foreach ($resultSet as $result) {
                $data[] = [
                    "visitor_name"     => $result->visitor_name,
                    "access_timestamp" => $result->access_timestamp
                ];
            }

            return $data;
        }
    }

?>
```

However, I cannot seem to get the concept on how to work this out with single-columned query results such as getting the `SUM`, `COUNT`, or even ids and specific data type. I've tried below code as I've tried to recreate provided answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29581318/7825830):

```
function isLinkIdValid($id)
{
    $sqlQry = "SELECT IF(COUNT(l.link_id) = 0, 0, 1) 'is_exist' FROM links l WHERE l.link_id = $id;";

    $result = $app->di->db->query($sqlQry);
    $result->setFetchMode(Phalcon\Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result = $result->fetchAll($result);

    return $result;
}
```

But, as i have expected, it would not work since `$app` (which is an instance of `Phalcon\Mvc\Micro` which is in `index.php`) is not accessible from the function.

Also, its best to explain to everyone that while I do have `models` for the database tables, I've separated all database logic from the model object to keep it clean and serve its only purpose - being a model. How I've done this is I've created a new folder named `/service` and creating service for each model that there is (for example: `VisitorService`).

To show everyone my code, I basically patterned it after [PhalconPHP's REST Tutorial](https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.4/en/tutorial-rest), below is a snippet of my code:

**index.php**:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro;
use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as PdoMySql;
use Phalcon\Http\Response;


    # Loader initialization and namespace registration
    $loader = new Loader();
    $loader->registerNamespaces([
        "MyApplication\Db\ShortLinks\DatabaseTables" => __DIR__ . "/models/",
        "MyApplication\Db\ShortLinks\Services"       => __DIR__ . "/services/"
    ]);
    $loader->register();


    # DependencyInjector initialization and instantiation of database connection
    $di = new FactoryDefault();
    $di->set("db", function() {
        return new PdoMySql([
            "host"     => "127.0.0.1",
            "username" => "username",
            "password" => "password",
            "dbname"  => "short_links"
        ]);
    });


    # Micro initialization, route definition
    $app = new Micro($di);
    $app->notFound(function() use ($app) {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(404, "Not Found");
        $response->setJsonContent([
            "status"  => 404,
            "message" => "The specified route was not found, or does not exist",
            "data"    => ""
        ]);

        return $response;
    });


    require "routes/visitor_route.php";


    $app->handle();

?>
```

**routes/visitor_route.php**

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Http\Response;
use MyApplication\Db\ShortLinks\Services;

require "services/visitor_service.php";


    $app->get('/v1/visitors/log/{id:[0-9]+}', function($id) use ($app) {
        $response = new Response();

        # validate id parameter
        if($id <= 0) {
            $response->setStatusCode(422, "Unprocessable Entity");
            $response->setJsonContent([
                "status"  => 422,
                "message" => "Invalid link id specified.",
                "data"    => ""
            ]);

            return $response;
        }

        $service = new Services\VisitorService();

        $response->setStatusCode(200, "OK");
        $response->setJsonContent([
            "status" => 200,
            "message" => "",
            "data" => $service->getVisitorLogByLinkId($id)
        ]);

        # This partially works, except that it does not return whether a link id is valid, so I'm trying to create a logic for one.
        // return $response;


        $tempService = new Services\LinkService();
        $tempResult = $tempService->isLinkIdValid($id);

        return print_r($tempResult);
    });

?>
```

**service/visitor_service.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyApplication\Db\ShortLinks\Services;

use MyApplication\Db\ShortLinks\DatabaseTables;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple as ResultSet;


    class VisitorService
    {
        # technically belongs to 'services/link_service.php' but placed here to shorten attached codes.
        function getAllLinks()
        {
            $sqlQry = "SELECT * FROM links;";

            $link = new DatabaseTables\Link();

            $resultSet = new ResultSet(null, $link, $link->getReadConnection()->query($sqlQry));

            $data = [];

            foreach ($resultSet as $result) {
                $data[] = [
                    "link_id"      => $result->link_id,
                    "description"  => $result->description,
                    "original_url" => $result->original_url,
                    "short_url"    => $result->short_url
                ];
            }

            return $data;
        }

        # technically belongs to 'services/link_service.php' but placed here to shorten attached codes.
        function createNewShortLink($link) 
        {
            $sqlQry = "INSERT INTO links VALUES (DEFAULT, '$link->description', '$link->original_url', $link->base_url, '$link->unique_key', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);";

            $link = new DatabaseTables\Link();
            $link->getReadConnection()->query($sqlQry);
        }

        # technically belongs to 'services/link_service.php' but placed here to shorten attached codes.
        # This is the experimental code i am working with
        function isLinkIdValid($id)
        {
            /*
                As it is, everything here doesn't work.
            */

            $sqlQry = "SELECT IF(COUNT(l.link_id) = 0, 0, 1) 'is_exist' FROM links l WHERE l.link_id = $id;";

            $result = $app->di->db->query($sqlQry);
            $result->setFetchMode(Phalcon\Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $result = $result->fetchAll($result);

            return $result;
        }

        function getVisitorLogByLinkId($id)
        {
            $sqlQry = "SELECT * FROM visitors v WHERE v.link_id = $id ORDER BY v.visitor_id DESC;";

            $visitor = new DatabaseTables\Visitor();

            $resultSet = new ResultSet(null, $visitor, $visitor->getReadConnection()->query($sqlQry));

            $data = [];

            foreach ($resultSet as $result) {
                $data[] = [
                    "visitor_name"       => $result->visitor_name,
                    "access_timestamp" => $result->access_timestamp
                ];
            }

            return $data;
        }
    }

?>
```

To summarize, I'm looking for a way to fetch single-columned data from my database using `RAW SQL Statements` inside `PhalconPHP`. I've dug up several resources but there's just too few of them, if not lacking.

EDIT 1: i know that how i implemented the service is not perfect, and that is prone to security attacks. but please focus on the issue main issue. i'll resolve other issues afterwards. also, what i'm looking for is to be able to use the PdoMysql stored in `$app->di["db"]` from the `index.php` much like how i managed to in `getAllLinks()` and `createNewShortLink($link)` functions. however, i made a "temporary" solution by passing in the PdoMysql object from the `$app->di["db"]` to the function like below:

```
function isLinkIdValid($dbConn, $id)
{
    $sqlQry = "SELECT IF(COUNT(l.link_id) = 0, 0, 1) 'is_exist' FROM links l WHERE l.link_id = $id;";

    $isExist = $dbConn->fetchAll($sqlQry, \Phalcon\Db::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $isExist;
}
```

Comment: first did you create models for you sql tables ? not using the good stuff that makes phalcon phalcon is big big mistake. as for accessing the di from any where you can use ```Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault::getDefault()``` this would return the default created and you can use it to access services for example ```Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault::getDefault()->get('db')```

Comment: as for selecting one column check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55400461/phalcon-model-order-by-item-popularity-number-of-appearances/55408358#55408358

Comment: hi @Talal, first i'd say sorry for not "using the good stuff". working them all out at the same time is a bit too much for me to absorb. to answer properly: **1.** Yes i did create models for my sql tables but they're as time as defining an empty class with no specific properties but extends to 'Phalcon\Mvc\Model' just like they've done it in the REST Tutorial on their documentation, check it here https://pastebin.com/cHPzAyvw. **2.** thank you the `::getDefault()` code, i'll try it out.

Comment: @Talal, as for selecting one column, i found a reference from PhalconPHP's PDO Adapter documentation that i copied and it worked exactly as i want here: https://imgur.com/a/hASl2Rp

Comment: you can use phalcon-dev tools. command line and very simple and it do all the " boring stuff " like creating models and its properties automatically and unleash the beast please. for example ```phalcon all-models``` inside the project dir will load your config and connects to db and create models for each table!!

Comment: @Talal really sorry to disappoint you that i'm not (yet) able unleash the best just yet. but i'll definitely get it all in no time. thank you for your assistance by the way! :)

Comment: no disappointment at all i'm just trying to help. give the tools a looksy you won't regret it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191484/discussion-between-nii-and-talal).